# How to choose XSD Attribute type with respect to a sibling attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd

How do you set the type of an attribute based on the value of another attribute in the same element.

There is a form that looks like:

```
<Products>
    <Product ProductCodeType="Default" ProductCode"789" />
    <Product ProductCodeType="Manufacturer" ProductCode"1234567891011" />
    <Product ProductCodeType="Supplier" ProductCode"Big1324" />
    <Product ProductCodeType="Default" ProductCode"7777777" />
</Products>
```

There are three different kinds of product code and they must each conform to a different definition as identified by the ProductCodeType attribute.

- Default          is numeric from three digits to seven digits.
- Manufacture is also numeric but must always be 13 digits.
- Supplier        is alpha-numeric without a defined length.

I have looked at assertions and alternatives in respect to [Conditional Type Assignment](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions) and [choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091715/xsd-a-xschoice-equivalent-for-attributes).  I am probably missing something simple and obvious.

For conventional wisdom I suggest ignoring the following XSD examples, as they haven't brought me any closer to a solution.

```
<xs:element name="Products" type="Prods" />

<xs:complexType name="Prods">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Product" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="abstractType" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Alternatives:

```
<xs:complexType name="Prod">
        <xs:attribute name="ProductCodeType" type="ProdCoTyp"/>
        <xs:attribute name="ProductCode" >
                <xs:alternative test="@ProductCodeType = 'Default'" type="def" />
                <xs:alternative test="@ProductCodeType = 'Manufacturer'" type="manu" />
                <xs:alternative test="@ProductCodeType = 'Supplier'" type="sup" />
        </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

Abstract Alternatives:

```
 <xs:complexType name="abstractType" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="ProductCodeType" type="ProdCoTyp"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Switch">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="abstractType">
            <xs:attribute name="ProductCode">
                <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:alternative test="@ProductCodeType = 'Default'" type="def" />
                <xs:alternative test="@ProductCodeType = 'Manufacturer'" type="manu" />
                <xs:alternative test="@ProductCodeType = 'Supplier'" type="sup" />
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Abstract Assertions

```
 <xs:complexType name="abstractType" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="ProductCodeType" type="Prod"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="deft">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="abstractType">
            <xs:attribute name="ProductCode" type="def" />
            <xs:assert test="@ProductCodeType = 'Default'"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="manuf">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="abstractType">
            <xs:attribute name="ProductCode" type="Manufacturer" />
            <xs:assert test="@ProductCodeType = 'manu'"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="suppr">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="abstractType">
            <xs:attribute name="ProductCode" type="Supplier" />
            <xs:assert test="@ProductCodeType = 'sup'"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>-
```

Product code types enumerations and type definitions.

```
<xs:simpleType name="ProdCoTyp">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Default"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Manufacturer"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Supplier"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="def">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minExclusive value="99"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="manu">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minExclusive value="999999999999"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999999999"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="sup" >
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z]*" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

For clarity, I get error messages like but not restricted to:

> S4s-elt-must-match.1: The Content Of 'simpleType' Must Match (annotation?, (restriction | List | Union)). A Problem Was Found Starting At: Alternative.

And

> S4s-elt-must-match.1: The Content Of 'ProductCode' Must Match (annotation?, (simpleType?)). A Problem Was Found Starting At: Alternative.

And

> S4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The Content Of 'deft' Is Invalid. Element 'assert' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often.

These error messages are indicative of the unfortunate state in which the goal of validating the conditional type assignments for attributes is not being achieved.
I am using online tools validate my XSD against a mock-up XML document.

Comment: Try to clarify your problem, XML are invalid? no xml at all? **X**ML **S**chema **D**efinition , so ti won't build an xml for you, it just defines it with constraints, etc. but xml is built with code.

Comment: `xs:assert` or `xs:alternative` should be the right way to achieve what you want; however they are only recognized in XSD 1.1. Thus check: 1) you properly declare your schema with this version; 2) ensure your parser is XSD-1.1 aware.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the schema is correctly declared.  As for the parsers, these are free online tools which don't advertise which version they support although when I've compared one against another they've given the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is a proposed schema for what you'd like to achieve, thanks to the use of `<xs:alternative>`s - I've built this upon some of your attempts, to retrieve the simple type definitions for your attributes.

I've added some comments in the schema to provide you with some explanations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="Products" type="Prods" />

    <xs:complexType name="Prods">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Product" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- Calling alternative definitions, depending on the ProductCodeType value -->
    <xs:element name="Product" type="Prod">
        <xs:alternative test="@ProductCodeType = 'Default'" type="ProdDefault"/>
        <xs:alternative test="@ProductCodeType = 'Manufacturer'" type="ProdManufacturer"/>
        <xs:alternative test="@ProductCodeType = 'Supplier'" type="ProdSupplier"/>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- Definition for the ProductCodeType attribute -->
    <xs:simpleType name="ProdCoTyp">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Default"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Manufacturer"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Supplier"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="Prod" abstract="true">
        <xs:attribute name="ProductCodeType" type="ProdCoTyp"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- The alternative content definitions for a <Product> -->
    <xs:complexType name="ProdDefault">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Prod">
                <xs:attribute name="ProductCode" type="def"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ProdManufacturer">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Prod">
                <xs:attribute name="ProductCode" type="manu"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ProdSupplier">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Prod">
                <xs:attribute name="ProductCode" type="sup"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- the definitions for the Default, Manufacturer and Supplier-specific @ProductCode -->
    <xs:simpleType name="def">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minExclusive value="99"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="manu">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minExclusive value="999999999999"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999999999"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="sup" >
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z]*" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work in any of the online validation tools available.  I have found an email thread that relates and that suggest this isn't possible.  https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-xml-schema-comments/2010JanMar/0011.html

Comment: Which one have you used? I've tested one or two, and didn't found any that were XSD **1.1** compliant, thus getting a message such as *A Problem Was Found Starting At: Alternative.*. I've developed this schema with oXygenXML editor and to me it works properly, validating the XML and the schema with Apache Xerces. Which parser / library are you using.

Comment: The site which I used was freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html It doesn't state the version of valitator it supports. Which gives a similar message.   I don't have access oXygenXML or the Xerces library but I will look into getting these.

Comment: Well, I can't ensure it, but to me this validator doesn't support XSD 1.1. Try Apache Xerces.

Comment: I have found a way to utilize Apache Xerces and this has worked.  Thank you.